# Fill grid with list data

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I have the following `list`:

```
list = {{114}, {59, 55}, {31, 28, 27}, {17, 14, 14, 13}}
```

The list data should be placed into a grid this way:

[image]

How can I fill and draw such a grid?

Comment: Have you tried anything with `Grid/Column` and friends? p.s. [Visualize Pascal's triangle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115610/5478), [73000](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73000/5478)

Comment: Related: [(9959)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9959/121)

Comment: You might need to tweak it, this is a start:  `Column[Grid[{#}, Frame -> All] & /@ list, Alignment -> Center, 
 Spacings -> 0]`

Comment: Using `Spacings -> -0.1` in Jason's code looks even better on my system.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard and Jason B: Thank you for the solution.